# Calendar: How to add additional month specific calendar views

Tags: views, datetime

By default - calendar will create Month, Week, Day, Year views for a calendar.  The month view is for the current month.  I need to create a Next Month view as well.  Or perhaps a view for a specific upcoming month.

How can I do this?

Mike R

Answer (score 0):

A view of the calendar should have previous and next buttons to link to views of the previous and next months. each of these have a specific url that you can reference or use if you need to access them other than through the buttons.